# SELECTing top N rows without ROWNUM?

Tags: oracle, rownum

I hope you can help me with my homework :)

We need to build a query that outputs the top N best paid employees.

My version works perfectly fine.
For example the top 3:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM staff
WHERE salary IN ( SELECT * 
                  FROM ( SELECT salary
                         FROM staff 
                         ORDER BY salary DESC ) 
                  WHERE ROWNUM <= 3 )
ORDER BY salary DESC
;
```

Note that this will output employees that are in the top 3 and have the same salary, too.

> 1: Mike, 4080
>   2: Steve, 2800
>   2: Susan, 2800
>   2: Jack, 2800
>   3: Chloe, 1400

---

But now our teacher does not allow us to use `ROWNUM`.
I searched far and wide and didn't find anything useable.

---

**My second solution** thanks to Justin Caves' hint.

First i tried this:

```
SELECT name, salary, ( rank() OVER ( ORDER BY salary DESC ) ) as myorder
FROM staff
WHERE myorder <= 3
;
```

The errormessage is: "myorder: invalid identifier"

Thanks to DCookie its now clear:

> "[...] Analytics are applied AFTER
>   the where clause is evaluated, which
>   is why you get the error that myorder
>   is an invalid identifier."

Wrapping a SELECT around solves this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT name, salary, rank() OVER ( ORDER BY salary DESC ) as myorder FROM staff )
WHERE myorder <= 3
;
```

---

My teacher strikes again and don't allow such exotic analytic functions.

**3rd solution** from @Justin Caves.

> "If analytic functions are also
>   disallowed, the other option I could
>   imagine-- one that you would never,
>   ever, ever actually write in practice,
>   would be something like"

```
SELECT name, salary
  FROM staff s1
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM staff s2
         WHERE s1.salary < s2.salary) <= 3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since this is homework, a hint rather than an answer.  You'll want to use analytic functions.  ROW_NUMBER, RANK, or DENSE_RANK can work depending on how you want to handle ties.

If analytic functions are also disallowed, the other option I could imagine-- one that you would never, ever, ever actually write in practice, would be something like

```
SELECT name, salary
  FROM staff s1
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM staff s2
         WHERE s1.salary < s2.salary) <= 3
```

With regard to performance, I wouldn't rely on the COST number from the query plan-- that's only an estimate and it is not generally possible to compare the cost between plans for different SQL statements.  You're much better off looking at something like the number of consistent gets the query actually does and considering how the query performance will scale as the number of rows in the table increases.  The third option is going to be radically less efficient than the other two simply because it needs to scan the STAFF table twice.

I don't have your STAFF table, so I'll use the EMP table from the SCOTT schema

The analytic function solution actually does 7 consistent gets as does the ROWNUM solution

```
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select ename, sal
  2    from( select ename,
  3                 sal,
  4                 rank() over (order by sal) rnk
  5            from emp )
  6*  where rnk <= 3
SQL> /

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
smith             800
SM0               950
ADAMS            1110


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3291446077

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-
| Id  | Operation                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time
|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |      |    14 |   672 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |      |    14 |   672 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|      |    14 |   140 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | EMP  |    14 |   140 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RNK"<=3)
   2 - filter(RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY "SAL")<=3)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        668  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        524  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          3  rows processed

SQL> select ename, sal
  2    from( select ename, sal
  3            from emp
  4           order by sal )
  5   where rownum <= 3;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
smith             800
SM0               950
ADAMS            1110


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1744961472

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |      |     3 |   105 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY          |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                  |      |    14 |   490 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|      |    14 |   140 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL   | EMP  |    14 |   140 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=3)
   3 - filter(ROWNUM<=3)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        668  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        524  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          3  rows processed
```

The COUNT(*) solution, however, actually does 99 consistent gets and has to do a full scan of the table twice so it is more than 10 times less efficient.  And it will scale much worse as the number of rows in the table increases

```
SQL> select ename, sal
  2    from emp e1
  3   where (select count(*) from emp e2 where e1.sal < e2.sal) <= 3;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
JONES            2975
SCOTT            3000
KING             5000
FORD             3000
FOO


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2649664444

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |    14 |   140 |    24   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER             |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | EMP  |    14 |   140 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |     4 |            |          |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |     4 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "EMP" "E2" WHERE
              "E2"."SAL">:B1)<=3)
   4 - filter("E2"."SAL">:B1)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         99  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        691  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        524  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          5  rows processed
```

Comment: Yep, i looked up RANK() and now i have found my second solution.

Comment: @Justin I showed my teacher the second solution. Now he doesn't allow such exotic analytic functions, too. Do you have second hint for me?

Comment: Thanks @Justin, that solution is quite unexpected and I still don't understand it. Going to review it today at home.

Comment: Now i got it. Isn't better than my first solution?
Costs: Solution 1: 8; Solution 2: 4; Solution 3: 6

Comment: @Pew - Updated with a more detailed discussion of the performance implications.

Comment: As always I thank for your help and information. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you must wrap the statement with another select is because the outer select statement is the one that limits your result set to the row numbers desired. Here's a [helpful link on analytics](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55). If you run the inner select by itself you'll see why you have to do this. Analytics are applied AFTER the where clause is evaluated, which is why you get the error that myorder is an invalid identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle? What about window functions?

```
select * from 
(SELECT s.*, row_number over (order by salary desc ) as rn FROM staff s )
where rn <=3
```

Comment: You did not apply any **window** functions.

Comment: Ok, ok. Analytic function. Doesn't matter.

Comment: I didn't try this because i was looking up for RANK because of @JustinCave's hint. But now i have the same solution.
But why must i wrap a SELECT around it to use the rn value?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `count(distinct <exp>)`, equal ranking top salaries will be treated as tie ranks.

```
select NAME, SALARY
from  STAFF STAFF1
where 3 >= ( select count(distinct STAFF2.SALARY) RANK
               from STAFF STAFF2
              where STAFF2.SALARY >= STAFF1.SALARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this in Oracle 12c

```
select NAME, SALARY
from  STAFF
order by SALARY DESC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
```

(FETCH FIRST syntax is new with Oracle 12c)

Comment: Explaining why this is the answer, would be also useful for the OP.

Comment: Yes ok and apologies for the code. Just thinking of an explanation

Comment: Any time you use "Top N" in a SELECT statement it works depending on the "ORDER BY" clause. In the WHERE clause, the part in brackets orders by descending salary so the top three of that are the highest salaries. Because the salaries are grouped together the statement doesn't care how many times they might appear. I'm then asking for any names which have that salary amount.

Comment: This is not valid syntax for Oracle.

Comment: @russ Edit to your to post instead of commenting/